# Changing Clock Skew for BasicHttpBinding not working

Tags: c#, wcf, wcf-binding, basichttpbinding, skew

I am trying to increase the clock skew on the BasicHtttpBinding programmatically.  I am using TransportSecurityBindingElement using CreateUserNameOverTransportBinding mode. I am able to change the binding element clock stew to 15 min( binding out at client side printed to file as shown below). But bootstrap element skew is not modified.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <configuration xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/.NetConfiguration/v2.0">
 <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <customBinding>
            <binding name="BasicHttpBinding">
                <security defaultAlgorithmSuite="Default" authenticationMode="UserNameOverTransport"
                    requireDerivedKeys="true" securityHeaderLayout="Lax" includeTimestamp="true"
                    keyEntropyMode="CombinedEntropy" messageSecurityVersion="WSSecurity10WSTrustFebruary2005WSSecureConversationFebruary2005WSSecurityPolicy11BasicSecurityProfile10">
                    <localClientSettings cacheCookies="true" detectReplays="false"
                        replayCacheSize="900000" maxClockSkew="00:15:00" maxCookieCachingTime="Infinite"
                        replayWindow="00:05:00" sessionKeyRenewalInterval="10:00:00"
                        sessionKeyRolloverInterval="00:05:00" reconnectTransportOnFailure="true"
                        timestampValidityDuration="00:05:00" cookieRenewalThresholdPercentage="60" />
                    <localServiceSettings detectReplays="false" issuedCookieLifetime="10:00:00"
                        maxStatefulNegotiations="128" replayCacheSize="900000" maxClockSkew="00:15:00"
                        negotiationTimeout="00:01:00" replayWindow="00:05:00" inactivityTimeout="00:02:00"
                        sessionKeyRenewalInterval="15:00:00" sessionKeyRolloverInterval="00:05:00"
                        reconnectTransportOnFailure="true" maxPendingSessions="128"
                        maxCachedCookies="1000" timestampValidityDuration="00:05:00" />
                    <secureConversationBootstrap />
                </security>
                <mtomMessageEncoding maxReadPoolSize="64" maxWritePoolSize="16"
                    messageVersion="Soap11" maxBufferSize="10485760" writeEncoding="utf-8">
                    <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
                        maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
                </mtomMessageEncoding>
                <httpsTransport manualAddressing="false" maxBufferPoolSize="524288"
                    maxReceivedMessageSize="10485760" allowCookies="false" authenticationScheme="Anonymous"
                    bypassProxyOnLocal="false" decompressionEnabled="true" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
                    keepAliveEnabled="true" maxBufferSize="10485760" proxyAuthenticationScheme="Anonymous"
                    realm="" transferMode="StreamedRequest" unsafeConnectionNtlmAuthentication="false"
                    useDefaultWebProxy="true" requireClientCertificate="false" />
            </binding>
        </customBinding>
    </bindings>
</system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

I am not able to modify the  elemet programatically. The difficulty I face here is to obtain the SecureConversationSecurityTokenParameters from the  TransportSecurityBindingElement. Please see my code below.

```
 public static Binding CreateCustomHttpSecuredStreamingUploadBinding(TimeSpan clockSkew)
    {
        CustomBinding myCustomBinding = new CustomBinding(GetHttpSecuredStreamingUploadBinding());
        TransportSecurityBindingElement security = myCustomBinding.Elements.Find<TransportSecurityBindingElement>();
        security.LocalClientSettings.MaxClockSkew = clockSkew;
        security.LocalServiceSettings.MaxClockSkew = clockSkew;

        SecureConversationSecurityTokenParameters secureConversation;
        secureConversation = security.EndpointSupportingTokenParameters.SignedEncrypted[0] as SecureConversationSecurityTokenParameters;

        if (secureConversation != null)
        {
            SecurityBindingElement bootstrap = secureConversation.BootstrapSecurityBindingElement;
            // Set the MaxClockSkew on the bootstrap element.
            bootstrap.LocalClientSettings.MaxClockSkew = clockSkew;
            bootstrap.LocalServiceSettings.MaxClockSkew = clockSkew;
        }        

        return myCustomBinding;  

     }



private static BasicHttpBinding GetHttpSecuredStreamingUploadBinding()
    {
        BasicHttpBinding basicHttpBinding = new BasicHttpBinding();
        basicHttpBinding.MessageEncoding = WSMessageEncoding.Mtom;
        basicHttpBinding.TransferMode = TransferMode.StreamedRequest;
        basicHttpBinding.Security.Mode = BasicHttpSecurityMode.TransportWithMessageCredential;
        basicHttpBinding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Certificate;
        basicHttpBinding.Security.Message.ClientCredentialType = BasicHttpMessageCredentialType.UserName;

        int MaxBufferSize = ConfigManager.GetInstance().MaxBufferSize(TConstants.HttpSecuredStreamingUpload, EndpointType.Client);
        basicHttpBinding.MaxBufferSize = MaxBufferSize;

        long maxReceivedMessageSize = ConfigManager.GetInstance().MaxReceivedMsgSize(TConstants.HttpSecuredStreamingUpload, EndpointType.Client);
        basicHttpBinding.MaxReceivedMessageSize = maxReceivedMessageSize;

        TdTimer timer = GetTimeOut(TConstants.HttpSecuredStreamingUpload, TConstants.SendTimeout);
        if (timer.isSet)
            basicHttpBinding.SendTimeout = timer.TimeOut;
        timer = GetTimeOut(TriadTransportConstants.HttpSecuredStreamingUpload, TConstants.ReceiveTimeout);
        if (timer.isSet)
            basicHttpBinding.ReceiveTimeout = timer.TimeOut;

        basicHttpBinding.ReaderQuotas = SetXmlDictionaryReaderQuotas(TConstants.HttpSecuredStreamingUpload);            
        return basicHttpBinding;
    }
```

The EndpointSupportingTokenParameters has a SignedEncrypted[0] element, but the Endorsing[0] is empty. so I use the code below but it returns null  on conversion to SecureConversationSecurityTokenParameters.

```
  secureConversation = security.EndpointSupportingTokenParameters.SignedEncrypted[0] as 
      SecureConversationSecurityTokenParameters;
```

There are lot of code snippets and help for WShttpBinding , but I cannot go for that as I am using streaming. Please help.